# has_been window function?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, window-functions

With [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5R42qXY5c7dvFe5K1MSqAC/0) following schema

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT
  , is_true BOOL
);
INSERT INTO test (id,is_true) VALUES (1,FALSE);
INSERT INTO test (id,is_true) VALUES (2,FALSE);
INSERT INTO test (id,is_true) VALUES (3,TRUE);
INSERT INTO test (id,is_true) VALUES (4,FALSE);
```

I make this query:

```
SELECT 
    is_true
FROM test;
```

which of course gives

```
FALSE
FALSE
TRUE
FALSE
```

what I want is some kind of window? function that does HAS_BEEN_TRUE rather than IS_TRUE and that respects the id ordering. This is why I think it may be a window function - because it has to do with a calculation over all rows that are like this.

It should return

```
FALSE -- never been TRUE
FALSE -- never been TRUE
FALSE -- even though it IS TRUE, it has never been so previously
TRUE  -- now it HAS BEEN true.
```

I would also accept

```
FALSE
FALSE
TRUE
TRUE
```

which I guess changes it to HAS_BEEN_OR_IS_TRUE. I really want to make this happen in redshift but Im happy to hear about any database where a window function does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A window `max()` of the boolean column should do what you want:

```
select t.*,
    max(is_true) over(
        order by id
        rows unbounded preceding
    ) has_been_or_is_true
from test t
```

Or, if you want to look only at previous row, ignoring the current row, we can refine the `row` frame:

```
select t.*,
    max(is_true) over(
        order by id
        rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
    ) has_been_true
from test
```

Comment: Thanks! And if the Max doesn't work on Boolean values? Can we use a SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE is_true = TRUE) in a window function instead of Max?

Comment: @BigBoy1337: if `max` does not work with booleans, then we would just use `case` expressions instead, like `max(case when is_true then 1 else 0 end) over(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sub-query, and check it yourself:

```sql
SELECT 
    id,
    case when exists (select 1 from test t2 where t2.id<t.id and t2.is_true = TRUE) then TRUE else FALSE end wind
FROM test t
```